# Trim repair on a 2003 Ford Focus

Tags: ford, repair, focus, trim

The door trim on the drivers side door of my 2003 Ford Focus has come loose at the front:

[image: Loose trim]

I'm guessing that a proper repair would require the interior door panel to be removed, and this seems like a lot of work for such an old car.  I would be happy with a "bodge job" repair if that could be guaranteed to last the few years the car has left to live.  Can anyone suggest the best way to do this?

I was thinking that double sided tape would do but the usual domestic double sided tape is too thin and I think it would come loose very quickly.  Some sort of tape or other adhesive that is thicker and with more "give" would be needed.  Can anyone suggest something like this that is easily obtainable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get something like [3M Super Weatherstrip Adhesive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00063X38M) or [Permatex Super Weatherstrip Adhesive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HBI9EQ). Follow the directions on the product. You'll probably want to use some painter's tape (the blue stuff) to keep the trim in place while it cures. If it's a leading edge (appears to be so), make sure you have the tape covering the point of the trim so the wind won't try to screw up your job (if you are planning on using the vehicle while it is curing).

You'll want to leave the tape in place for probably 24 hours at least to ensure good bonding of the adhesive. The reason I suggest to use the blue tape is that it shouldn't leave a residue behind when you pull it off. Whatever you use will look ugly in the mean time, but have no fear, it's the end result you want.

Oh, one last thing ... ensure you clean the area where you want to apply the adhesive before you apply or your fix will not last. Pull up the trim the best you can and get all of the old glue off. It doesn't have to be perfect, but you should do the best you can on it. Make sure you have plenty of painted area to put the adhesive on. (**EDIT NOTE:** Leave the small piece of plastic on the door if it is firmly affixed as it would be a good point for adhesion between the trim and the door.)

Comment: Thanks :-) Permatex is available in the UK but Amazon retailers seem to charge exorbitant postage - maybe they are getting from the US. Anyhow there's a chap on eBay UK selling Permatex at sensible prices so I'll give him a try.

Comment: @JohnRennie - Sorry, I wasn't suggesting you use Amazon to purchase the items, just using their website to show you an example of what I was talking about. I don't think I'd use Amazon in the UK, either ... unless Amazon Prime works the same way over there it does here in the US ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks it is held by plastic rivets. You may be able to get them from dealer. Dealer can certainly help you with the information and if you don't ask them to fix, it shouldn't cost you anything.

Comment: Thanks David. There are prongs in the trim that push through the door skin, and I'd guess there are clips on the inside of the door that attach to these prongs. A proper repair would be to remove the interior door panel and reattach the clips, but getting the interior door panel off seems a lot of work.