# How to properly reaffix this rubber (?) belt onto the car body?

Tags: body-work

I'm not sure if this belt is completely for decoration only. It looks like a kind of plastic or rubber. How to properly reaffix this belt onto the car body?

Edit: As per comment request, the car is a 2015 Nissan Versa Note hatchback

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this - so, not an answer - But, long ago, my wife reattached this strip on her Chevette with Elmer's glue.  To my amazement, it was still attached when we got rid of the car, over a year later.

Comment: Definitively looks like a glue-on or tape-on trim piece. If it had fasteners/clips there should have been a clip or hole visible were it has pulled away from the door.

Comment: What make, model, year, and options level is the car? This will help identify the part and the *installation instructions* for the part. So even if you don't need the part the instructions showing how it was installed originally will help re-install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim repair on a 2003 Ford Focus](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18693/trim-repair-on-a-2003-ford-focus)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the best way to reaffix this is by using double sided tape. 3M brand tape is probably the most widely used, but that'd be a guess on my part (no affiliation). You'd need to pull the rubber piece entirely off of the vehicle, but before you do, take a long piece of painters tape and place it just under the front where it's still attached all the way to the rubber piece on the back door. This will help you align it when sticking it back on there. Also, place a small vertical piece at the front. You'll carefully pull what is left stuck on the door, then clean the old tape off. Apply new tape to the rubber piece, leaving the exposed side left with the covering still on the outside sticky part. Once ready, ensure the area is completely clean and dry, then stick it on there. If you start to peel the outside protective layer off by just a couple of inches and let the end hang down, you can gradually pull it away from the rubber piece as you're sticking it to the door. That way when starts going on, it'll be straight or you can adjust it a little to ensure it's right. Much easier and straighter than if you just tried to stick it on there.

Answer (score 5):

The trim is often referred to as body side molding. Its purpose is to protect the body from minor dings and scratches typical of a shopping carriage or bumping the door while exiting the vehicle. It is not structural but is more than decorative. This type of trim is typically held on with an adhesive. It could be in the form of a double-sided tape (sticky on both sides) or a liquid glue-like substance. To reattatch the trim you could try to use some trim adhesive or tape. The issue is going to be the point where the trim is still attached and getting the new adhesive up to that point without leaving a gap. I would use a hair dryer to loosen the adhesive. Gently push a plastic scraper under the trim to remove it. Don't pull too hard as this may stretch and distort. Clean both the back of the trim and the door and reattach with new adhesive, tape type would be the easiest.